# Angular 6 SiteMap.xml - What is the best approach

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I need to include in my project sitemap.xml.

I know where I need to put it.

```
"apps": [
{
 [...]
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "sitemap.xml",
    "robots.txt"
  ],
 [...]
}
]
```

but not sure how to generate it.
I have many URLs that are dynamic

what is the best approach?

Comment: Please try https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/, they have three different mode of generation. One of them is free and other two are with addition features. The available formats and protocols for the sitemap can be found at https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue you can check my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817960/how-to-let-sitemap-generator-fully-crawl-angular-router-for-spa). You have to probably make the xml manually. or try botmap.io but you have to specifically use href for the pages you want to generate. If your webpage isn't big you can just make xml manually like I did. For each route in your router you just create a point in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>http://margvel.com</loc><priority>0.5</priority></url>
<url><loc>http://margvel.com/projects</loc><priority>0.5</priority></url>
<url><loc>http://margvel.com/jobs</loc><priority>0.5</priority></url>
<url><loc>http://margvel.com/education</loc><priority>0.5</priority></url>
<url><loc>http://margvel.com/resume</loc><priority>0.5</priority></url>
<url><loc>http://margvel.com/contact</loc><priority>0.5</priority></url>
</urlset>
```